# converting a delineated string into an array path in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'd appreciate any help I could get with this — I've been scouring stack overflow and couldn't find anything that directly related with what I'm trying to accomplish.

**Issue:**  I'm trying to update a specific name/value pair in a JSON file, and I'm trying to do it by sending specific parameters through an AJAX call to a PHP file.  Two of the parameters are the path (delineated with hyphens) to the name, and the value that I'm swapping in.

A small portion of the JSON:

```
{
  "character" : 
  {             
    "name" : "Foo",
    "species" : "Bar",
  }
}
```

Using this JSON as an example, I'm trying to update a specific array value, such as:

```
$char['character']['name']
```

I'm passing a variable to the PHP file with the path information, such as:

```
updater.php?char=character-name&val=Newname
```

Is there a way to convert the string "character-name" (or any string for that matter with a particular delineation) to the path in an Array, like `$char['character']['name']`?

Comment: I would propose doing it correctly using arrays from the start.  See below.

Comment: See my response.  I can't store a proper array tag as a form field attribute (i.e. class or ID name).

Comment: You are doing the AJAX improperly.

Comment: That really isn't helpful.

Comment: Well, there is no form or AJAX code to help with.  You are hacking some stuff together and sending it to PHP and wanting a solution to unhack it.  All I'm saying is send it in a useful way and you won't have 2 hacks.

Comment: AJAX is just the means of passing the information, not the center of the solution that I was looking for.  Thanks for posting your answer though.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not only read the value at the specified path, but also update the json, I would suggest something like

```
<?php
function json_replace_path($json, $path, $newValue)
{
    $json = json_decode($json);

    $pathArray = explode('-', $path);
    $currentElement = $json;

    foreach ($pathArray as $part)
    {
        $currentElement = &$currentElement->$part;
    }

    $currentElement = $newValue;

    return json_encode($json);
}

$json = '{"character":{"name":"Foo","species":"Bar","other":{"first_name":"Jeff","last_name":"Atwood"}}}';
echo json_replace_path($json, 'character-name', 'new name') . "\n";
echo json_replace_path($json, 'character-species', 'new species') . "\n";
echo json_replace_path($json, 'character-other-last_name', 'Bridges') . "\n";
```

Does not support JSON including arrays, though.

Comment: This is perfect.  This is exactly what I was looking for — something that'd allow me to dynamically set the path and value, and update the JSON.  Thanks much Felix!

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = explode("-", $_GET['char']);

$char=json_decode(....);  //your json string

$char[$array[0]][$array[1]]=$_GET['val'];
```

Comment: I was going to select this as the answer, but blue112 has a more flexible answer that will go as deep as I need to  without having to manually enter in array values.  Thanks for posting!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work, I guess :

```
$a = explode("-", $_GET['char']);
$array = ...; //Your json array here

while (is_array($array) && count($a) > 0)
{
    $array = $array[array_shift($a)];
}
```

Comment: I think this is leaning towards what I need to do.  I'll test it out and post a follow-up in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `updater.php?character[name]=Newname`?  Then you can get it with:

```
echo $_GET['character']['name'];
```

Makes much more sense.  Why concatenate things and then try and separate them into an array when you can just use an array from the start?

Comment: It's not so simple as just doing that.  I've got a form that has the JSON path encoded into the fields — and it really could be to any depth level such as `$char['character']['profile']['name']` or `$char['character']['equipment']['armor'][1]['name']`

I need that path to be suitable for passing as a form element attribute, such as a class or ID value.